# Apachectl creates more than one process even with flag -X set

Tags: apache, debugging, process, gdb

I am trying to use *gdb* to attach to apache2.4. Although I am running Apache HTTP Server as a single process, there are three process created. The problem is that I don't know which process to connect to with gdb.

Command that I use to run apache:
`sudo apachectl -X`

Process created:

```
www-data    4065  7.2  0.3 936096 67924 pts/0    Sl+  10:09   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -X
root        4066  0.0  0.0 119252 11032 ?        Ss   10:09   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -X
root        4067  1.0  0.1 651768 19152 ?        Ssl  10:09   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -X
```

Answer (score 0):

I attached to www-data process (pid number: 4065) and it works.